# Electron distribution build displays a blank page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, desktop-application

I am working now upon an `Electron` + `React-JS` app, and have to create a distribution build. The problem is that after creating that build and launching the resulted file (in our case the compiled app), the app shows me a blank screen without rendering any of `./src` folder's content. Everything's working well when launching `Electron` in dev mode.

For some reference, I'll attach the contents of my `package.json`, electron's `main.js` and React's `index.js` and `App.js` files.

> Package.json

```
{
  ...
  "build": {
    "appId": ...,
    "mac": {
      "category": ...
    },
    "files": [
      "build/**/*",
      "node_modules/**/*"
    ],
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "assets"
    }
  },
  "main": "public/electron.js",
  "homepage": "./",
  "dependencies": {
    "@reach/router": "^1.2.1",
    "apexcharts": "^3.10.1",
    "apisauce": "^1.1.1",
    "cross-env": "^6.0.3",
    "electron-is-dev": "^1.1.0",
    "formik": "^2.0.4",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "^16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.11.0",
    "react-loading-overlay": "^1.0.1",
    "react-notification-system": "^0.2.17",
    "react-pin-input": "^0.9.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0",
    "react-table": "^6.10.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "reduxsauce": "^1.1.1",
    "seamless-immutable": "^7.1.4",
    "yup": "^0.27.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "react-start": "react-scripts start",
    "react-build": "react-scripts build",
    "react-test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "react-eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "electron-postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "electron-start": "concurrently \"cross-env BROWSER=none yarn react-start\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron .\"",
    "electron-build": "electron-builder",
    "release": "yarn react-build && electron-builder --publish=always",
    "build": "yarn react-build && yarn electron-build",
    "build-mw": "yarn react-build && electron-builder -mw"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^5.0.0",
    "electron": "^7.1.1",
    "electron-builder": "^22.1.0",
    "wait-on": "^3.3.0"
  }
}
```

> Electron main.js

```
const electron = require('electron');
const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;

const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');
const isDev = require('electron-is-dev');

let mainWindow;

function createWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 900, height: 680});
  mainWindow.loadURL(isDev ? 'http://localhost:3000' : `file://${path.join(__dirname, '../build/index.html')}`);
  mainWindow.on('closed', () => mainWindow = null);
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

> React index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

> React App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import {persistStore} from 'redux-persist';
import {PersistGate} from 'redux-persist/integration/react';

import Navigation from './Navigation';
import {RootReducer} from './Redux/Root.Reducer';

const store = createStore(RootReducer);
const persistor = persistStore(store);

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
      <Navigation />
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

P.S. As opposed to the tutorials found on the internet about linking Electron with React-JS, I've placed Electron's main.js file under `./public` directory, in my React project.

Comment: Open the dev tools and look for exceptions. Add logging to see how far your app got. If neither of those help you may need to use debugging tools to understand why it isn’t completing startup.

Comment: I've tried to make a clean React-JS Project and install Electron. There I've built the distribution version and launched it successfully, but in case of my app, it seems like it doesn't see the react part, as in devtools I see the render of the index.html placed in public folder, and the function from index.js which shall operate with the `.root` div element isn't even called, or smth like that. In console there aren't any errors...

Comment: Open the devtools in production mode and look for exceptions. Add logging to see how far your app got. If neither of those help you may need to use debugging tools to understand why it isn’t completing startup.

Comment: @Eugen-AndreiColiban git any luck with because I am also facing the same issue.